# Can you prove why the recurrence $3P_{n} - 2P_{n + 1} = P_{n - 1}$ holds for some (a subset of the) prime numbers?

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, prime-numbers, recurrence-relations, pattern-recognition

> Can you prove why this recurrence relation holds for some (a subset of the) prime numbers? And does it go on infinitely? (I think it does)
>
> $$3P_{n} - 2P_{n + 1} = P_{n - 1}$$

First few values for which it applies:

$5,
7,
13,
20,
25,
26,
28,
45,
49,
60,
64,
78,
88,
89,
93,
95,
113,
136,
144,
148,
152,
159,
182,
212,
225,
229,
230,
236,
243,
247,
249,
262,
265,
277,
286,
288,
291,
302,
315,
323$

E.G:   For $n = 5, P_{n} = 11, P_{n + 1} = 13, P_{n - 1} = 7:$

$3(11) - 2(13) = 7$

$3P_{5} - 2P_{6} = P_{4}$

...&c for the others

Comment: does this help ... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap#Lower_bounds

Comment: @Donald Splutterwit: A little bit, thanks for the link. It's just a curiosity I think though.

Comment: the asymptotic behaviour is given by equation $(9)$ here ... https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeConstellation.html

Answer (score 4):

Using the standard [prime gap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap) notation gives that

$$g_n = p_{n+1} - p_{n} \implies p_{n+1} = p_{n} + g_{n} \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

$$p_{n} = p_{n-1} + g_{n-1} \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Next, \eqref{eq2A} in \eqref{eq1A} gives

$$p_{n+1} = p_{n-1} + g_{n-1} + g_{n} \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

Substituting \eqref{eq2A} and \eqref{eq3A} into your relation results in

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
& 3p_{n} - 2p_{n + 1} = p_{n - 1} \\
& 3(p_{n-1} + g_{n-1}) - 2(p_{n-1} + g_{n-1} + g_{n}) = p_{n - 1} \\
& 3p_{n-1} + 3g_{n-1} - 2p_{n-1} - 2g_{n-1} - 2g_{n} = p_{n - 1} \\
& p_{n-1} + g_{n-1} - 2g_{n} = p_{n - 1} \\
& g_{n-1} = 2g_{n}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

Thus, your relation holds whenever any prime gap is double that of the next prime gap. With your example of $n = 5$, we have $g_{n-1} = 11 - 7 = 4$ and $g_{n} = 13 - 11 = 2$.

As for whether or not there's an infinite number of primes where \eqref{eq4A} holds, I'm quite certain that is currently unknown, but it's conjectured to be the case. Note there are infinitely many [prime $k$-tuples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_k-tuple) which are [admissible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_k-tuple#Admissibility) and, in the cases  where they also represent a [prime constellation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_k-tuple#Prime_constellations), then \eqref{eq4A} is true, e.g., your example of $(0, 4, 6)$ (which is called a [prime triplet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_triplet)), $(0, 8, 12)$, $(0, 12, 18)$, etc. The "Admissibility" section also states

> It is conjectured that every admissible $k$-tuple matches infinitely many positions in the sequence of prime numbers. However, there is no admissible tuple for which this has been proven except the $1$-tuple ($0$). Nevertheless, by [Yitang Zhang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yitang_Zhang)'s famous proof of $2013$ it follows that there exists at least one $2$-tuple which matches infinitely many positions; subsequent work showed that some $2$-tuple exists with values differing by $246$ or less that matches infinitely many positions.<sup>[[2]](https://asone.ai/polymath/index.php?title=Bounded_gaps_between_primes)</sup>

In particular, the [prime $k$-tuple conjecture](https://primes.utm.edu/glossary/page.php?sort=PrimeKtupleConjecture) states

> ... that every admissible pattern for a prime constellation occurs infinitely often ...

This conjecture implies there are an infinite number of primes which satisfy \eqref{eq4A}.

Comment: Thanks for the quick, concise and comprehensive answer. Regarding the prime numbers, do you think a formula will ever be found that has say five terms or fewer, that will allow you to find $P_{n}$ in terms of $n$? Or has it been proven that such a formula cannot exist? I know it might seem outlandish, but I firmly believe the Ancient Greeks found one and it is lost to time.

Comment: @Joebloggs You're welcome. As for a "formula" for $p_n$ in terms of $n$ consisting of just a few terms, say five or fewer, I don't think that will ever happen with an expression that works for all $n$. Note Wikipedia's [formula for primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formula_for_primes) gives some examples which don't quite meet what you're looking for, but with the [formula based on a system of Diophantine equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formula_for_primes#Formula_based_on_a_system_of_Diophantine_equations) one possibly being closest.